# Flat Connections on the Cotangent Complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cotangent-complex

I'm trying to find a reference which defines and discusses some properties of connections and flat connections on the cotangent complex in a homotopical setting. That is to say, a connection or flat connection on a morphism of highly structured ring spectra. This is the sort of thing I feel like might be written down somewhere by Jacob Lurie or John Francis, and I'm actively looking for it, but of course that's a lot of ground to cover. Also, it might be written down somewhere else (perhaps Illusie or someone defined a notion of a connection on the cotangent complex at some point that I can generalize to the setting of ring spectra).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you look up "Atiyah extension" in Illusie's first volume.  There is a definition using the cotangent complex in place of the sheaf of relative differentials (as in the "usual" definition).

Comment: Thanks @JasonStarr, at the moment I'm only finding something about the Atiyah class. This seems to be an obstruction to supporting a connection, or something along these lines. Is that what you're referring to?